# how to make real time code in C#

Tags: c#

I want to read sms from my GSM modem.
I wrote C# code.
This code run when I click start button.
I want to my program read sms when received, not click button.
thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567978/receive-sms-through-gsm-modem Does that help?

Comment: This is good post, but I need simple code. I want to learn it. How to do it?

Comment: And why do you think you need real time code to read SMS from a GSM modem? You definitely should read up on what real time means in programming.

Comment: AT+CNMI is the way to request TE notifications from the GSM device for new messages.  Prudence dictates you would still poll examining the message list for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is keyed to activate when you press a button, some method is called.  You need to call this method when SMS data is received instead. This could be done using threads (SMS thread and main thread showing data) although it could just as easily be done using a cycle. In pseudo code:

```
while (don't quit) {
    display page;
    check for sms data;
    sleep for small time to allow other OS programs to run also;
}
```

This is a "tight loop" and can use excessive amounts of CPU time depending on the code of the actual steps. For a tight program loop one simple method is to apply some sort of sleep method.

There are other ways to do the same thing, visitor pattern could probably be used, threads, etc...

It seems that you are only lacking the cycle. Your programs is probably more like:

```
while (don't quit) {
    display page.
    wait for button press.
}
```

although that flow wouldn't be obviously apparent at first glance without studying your program flow.

If you are using triggers (the button press is probably a trigger) you can trigger on a timer that fires as often as you want (100ms, 1 second, whatever) that checks for SMS data when fired, if there is SMS data it updates the form.

Many, many ways to do this. A quick Google for "program flow" doesn't find any useful links at first glance that would explain the many ways you could do this. Perhaps looking at other's code would help. I've often searched open source repositories for code I could look at to see how someone else did something.